# Changing prime meridian of map?

Tags: coordinate-system, fme-form, mapguide

I am working with the Natural Earth world map as a SHP file, but when I try to change the prime meridian (`PRIMEM`) of the coordinate system

> GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

I get this:

[image]

Projections seem to give the same results.  What is happening here?

Comment: Do you need polygons? - if lines then reproject your data to the meridian you want.

Comment: just noticed the mapguide tag. is this shapefile or sdf, oracle?

Comment: Shapefile, loaded into MapGuide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might try exporting the data or possibly run it through a fix geometry (I use et geotools).
It looks to me lie with the new meridian you are splitting some polygons and that is causing the fill to "leak" out.

[image: arcmap1]

[image: arcmap2]

[image: et tools]

Comment: What does a fix geometry involve?  Export it to what format?

Comment: fix geomtery is in et tools. it outputs a shape file.   geometry repair is avail at the editor level arcmap and performs it on the existing feature class.

Comment: You were right, the shapes are getting "stretched" across the map which was causing the distortion.  The shapes need to be "cut" before changing the meridian.

Answer (score 3):

natural earth is cropped at 180°, so all is ok, if your prime-meridian is 0°. when you change the prime-meridian e.g. to 90°east some country-boundaries go beyond the right or left map-border and "continue" on the other side of the map.

Comment: Is there any way to change the meridian and not cause this?

Comment: as far as I know there is no easy way, you have to do this manually, which is a real pain. but perhaps anyone knows an easy way??

Comment: I am working on a data translation script to do this (cut the shapes and rotate meridian).  Unfortunately we use proprietary tools (FME) so I cannot post a general solution.